# ¿Como puedo obtener el nombre de la maquina (cliente) usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Existe alguna forma en la que pueda obtener el nombre de la maquina (cliente) usando Javascript?

Comment: Hace tiempo se podría lograr con IE, pero actualmente por cuestiones de seguridad no se puede leer el nombre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta es que NO se puede por restricciones del navegador, pero otra información como Browser, Sistema Operativo, Resolución de pantalla, entre otros, es posible obtenerla desde Javascript.

Comment: Restricciones del navegador, en todo caso.

Answer (score 5):

La respuesta es simple: **NO**, excepto en algunas versiones de IE.

Algunas referencias:

[How can I read the client's machine/computer name from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922476/how-can-i-read-the-clients-machine-computer-name-from-the-browser) (aquí explica como obtenerlo con IE)

[Read the Computer Name using javascript in mozila browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589412/read-the-computer-name-using-javascript-in-mozila-browser?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la respuesta, actualmente por cuestiones de seguridad, actualmente **NO es posible** leer el "`Computer Name`" mediante `JavaScript`; se podría realizar mediante un control `Active X`, pero debes obligar a tus usuarios a usar `Internet Explorer`.

[Writing an ActiveX control in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/270811/Get-Computer-Name-from-ActiveX-control) (inglés)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener los datos del navegador que está usando y algunas cosas extra, pero detalles de la maquina desde donde se ejecutando el navegador, no.